# Configure FTP access to CentOS VM on Azure

Tags: centos, ftp, azure, endpoint

I have just set up a Virtual Machine running CentOS through Azure. In order to be able to access the virtual machine through an FTP client, I have enabled the FTP endpoint.

[image]

When I try to FTP in to the server, I see this in FileZilla:

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
```

There are no issues with the IP address as I am able to access the server through SSH.

What am I missing?

Comment: Checked firewall?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my IP Tables at the OS level.

I ran the following commands on CentOS to allow communication on port 20, 21 and 22.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Then run:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

The above three rules should be above the `REJECT ALL` rule under the `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)` in order to be considered.